# awk csv file append numbers

Tags: awk

I am have the below CSV file

```
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,14/05/2016,ABC
vol123,13/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,18/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,19/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,20/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,22/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC
```

I want to change this as below,

```
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC1
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC2
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC3
vol123,14/05/2016,ABC4
vol123,13/05/2016,ABC5
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC6
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC7
vol123,18/05/2016,ABC8
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC9
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC10
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC1
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC2
vol123,19/05/2016,ABC3
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC4
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC5
vol123,20/05/2016,ABC6
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC7
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC8
vol123,22/05/2016,ABC9
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC10
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC1
```

I want to a append number to last column. Number range is 1 to 10. I want 1 again on the 11th record so append should work in loop.

Please help me as I am unable to get this using awk command.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk` to append the line number (`NR`) to each line with:

```
awk '{print $0 NR}' file
```

If you want to print the remainder when the line number is divided by 10:

```
awk '{print $0 NR%10}' file
```

That prints what you want except it prints `0` instead of `10`. If you need `10`, you can calculate `(NR - 1)%10 + 1`:

```
awk '{print $0 (NR - 1)%10 + 1}' file
```

Result:

```
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC1
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC2
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC3
vol123,14/05/2016,ABC4
vol123,13/05/2016,ABC5
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC6
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC7
vol123,18/05/2016,ABC8
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC9
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC10
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC1
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC2
vol123,19/05/2016,ABC3
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC4
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC5
vol123,20/05/2016,ABC6
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC7
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC8
vol123,22/05/2016,ABC9
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC10
vol123,12/05/2016,ABC1
```